# How can I eliminate having to not repeat the same code

Tags: javascript

I have a script that adds items to a Netsuite record. In this case 22 items needs to be added but the value lines in the below are different for each item. Rather than having to repeat the same lines over and over again is there a better way to do this.

Code below:

```
             rec.setCurrentSublistValue(
             {
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'item',
                value: 1261,
                forceSyncSourcing: true
             } )
             // Add item description
             rec.setCurrentSublistValue(
             {
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'description',
                value: 'Charge Description'
             } )
             // Add item quantity
             rec.setCurrentSublistValue(
             {
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'quantity',
                value: 1,
                forceSyncSourcing: true
             } )
             // Add Estimated Unit Cost F/X
             rec.setCurrentSublistValue(
             {
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'custcol_est_unit_cost_fx',
                value: handlingBuy,
                forceSyncSourcing: true
             } )
             // Add Margin
             rec.setCurrentSublistValue(
             {
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'custcol_orig_rate',
                value: handlingSell,
             } )
             // Commmit The Item
             rec.commitLine(
             {
                "sublistId": "item"
             } );
```

Comment: Use an array of objects instead, and iterate over it?

Comment: not sure if it is the answer to your question, but for such cases, we create a utility or model function which accepts an array & inside that function we iterate & find something based on conditions. so function, array, & a map is probably what you need.